# I want to concatenate these case statements

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I'm getting multiple results from these statements and want to concatenate these. Please help with syntax and structure

```
 (SELECT NVL (
              CASE WHEN (csi.hello = DT.S)
                     THEN 'Task IS ALREADY DONE'   
                     WHEN VV.Mo LIKE NULL
                     THEN  'The model is not available'  
                     WHEN (B.tsk = '7')
                     THEN 'The task status has been Cancelled' 
                     WHEN (B.tski = '14')
                     THEN  'The task has been Assigned'  
                     WHEN (B.tsko = '11001')
                     THEN 'The task has been Return Part STATUS'    
                     END, '')RMA_CRITERIA,
```

Answer (score 1):

Use string concatenation:

```
 SELECT (CASE WHEN csi.hello = DT.S THEN 'Task IS ALREADY DONE;' ELSE '' END ||  
         CASE WHEN VV.Mo IS NULL THEN 'The model is not available;' ELSE '' END ||  
         CASE WHEN B.tsk = '7' THEN 'The task status has been Cancelled;' ELSE '' END || 
         CASE WHEN B.tski = '14' THEN  'The task has been Assigned;' ELSE '' END ||  
         CASE WHEN B.tsko = '11001' THEN 'The task has been Return Part STATUS;' ELSE '' END
        ) as RMA_CRITERIA,
```

Note that this adds a separator (`;`), although you do not specify one.  Also `LIKE NULL` always returns the equivalent of false; I assume you intend `IS NULL`.  And the `ELSE ''` is redundant in Oracle, but it makes the intention clear.